# Access denied for web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, windows-server-2008

I have a website on my IIS server and a web service installed on the same website. My question is pretty simple. I am trying to move a file from the web service to one folder to another folder located in the website. But I get a message "Access denied to the specific folder"

Any help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account under which IIS is running is probably a member of the `IIS_IUSRS` group.  You could grant that group access rights on the folder.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I tried before with write permission. After your suggestion I tried write and modify. And that worked.